# How to get a Value from Table Iteration in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, iteration

I am new to programming, working in asp.net.
I made a table with iteration, and here is my code:

```
        int row2 = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["coll"]);
        Session.Add("sumColl", row2);
        TableRow tr2;
        TableCell tc2;
        TextBox tb2;
        RequiredFieldValidator rfv;

        for (int j = 0; j < row2; j++)
        {
            tr2 = new TableRow();
            tc2 = new TableCell();
            tc2.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl((j + 1).ToString()));
            tr2.Cells.Add(tc2);
            tc2 = new TableCell();
            tb2 = new TextBox();
            tb2.ID = "name" + (j + 1).ToString();
            btn = new Button();
            btn.ID = "search" + (j + 1).ToString();
            btn.Text = "Search";
            btn.OnClientClick = "javascript:openChild('popupA.aspx?dest=" + tb2.ID + "','win2')";
            btn.CausesValidation = false;
            rfv = new RequiredFieldValidator();
            rfv.ID = "rfvR" + (j + 1).ToString();
            rfv.ControlToValidate = tb2.ID;
            rfv.Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic;
            rfv.ErrorMessage = "**";
            tc2.Controls.Add(tb2);
            tc2.Controls.Add(btn);
            tc2.Controls.Add(rfv);
            tr2.Cells.Add(tc2);
            tblA.Rows.Add(tr2);
        }
```

I want to get values from the database, where the input came from the textbox in the table above.
After I get the values I want to sum them.
The problem is I don't know how to get the input from iteration above.
I did something like below code.

```
        int sumsColl = Convert.ToInt32(Session["sumColl"]);
        double sum_coll = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < sumsColl; j++)
        {
            TextBox tb2 = new TextBox();
            tb2 = this.Page.FindControl("name" + (j + 1).ToString()) as TextBox;
            if (tb2 != null)
            {                    
                string sqlCol2 = "select p from somewhere where nameColl = '" + tb2.Text + "'";
                DataTable dtcol2 = db.setDataTableSQL(sqlCol2);
                for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
                {
                   Session.Add("P" + (j + 1).ToString(), dtcol2.Rows[0]["p"]);
                }

                sum_coll = sum_coll + Convert.ToDouble(Session["P"+(j + 1).ToString()]);
            }

        }

        if (sum_coll < value)
        {
            Msg.Text = "Error . " + Msg.Text;
            valid = false;
        }
```

I know this is a mess, please help me and let me know if you need another clue.

Comment: Wow.  Okay, I think your best bet is to maybe ask several more focused questions (not all at once.)  Try to do a small chunk, see if that works, and if you get stuck, ask that specific question.  

Something that will also help with this question is adding some text about what you're trying to do exactly.  You gave a big chunk of code at the beginning, but often people don't want to wade into code to figure out what it is supposed to do.  It's usually better to tell them what you're trying to do first, and then they can start reading the code with that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to do. Try DataGrid or DataGridView, ListView controls to display data. Your code seems very complicated. There are controls out there that specifically displays tabular data.